# group two dataframes with different sizes in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pandas-groupby

I've got two data frames, one has historical prices of stocks in this format:

| year | Company1 | Company2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1980 | 4.66 | 12.32 |
| 1981 | 5.68 | 15.53 |

etc with hundreds of columns, then I have a dataframe specifing a company, its sector and its country.

| company 1 | industrials | Germany |
| --- | --- | --- |
| company 2 | consumer goods | US |
| company 3 | industrials | France |

I used the first dataframe to plot the prices of various companies over time, however, I'd like to now somehow group the data from the first table with the second one and create a separate dataframe which will have form of sectors total value of time, ie.

| year | industrials | consumer goods | healthcare |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1980 | 50.65 | 42.23 | 25.65 |
| 1981 | 55.65 | 43.23 | 26.15 |

Thank you

Comment: Unpivot the first table on year and join with second table on company

Comment: how exactly would I unpivot it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following, assuming df_1 is your DataFrame with price of stock per year and company, and df_2 your DataFrame with information on the companies:

```
# turn company columns into rows
df_1 = df_1.melt(id_vars='year', var_name='company')

df_1 = df_1.merge(df_2)
# groupby and move industry to columns
output = df_1.groupby(['year', 'industry'])['value'].sum().unstack('industry')
```

Output:

```
industry  consumer goods  industrials
year                                 
1980               12.32         4.66
1981               15.53         5.68
```

Comment: what exactly should be the var_name='company' ? Cuz the df_1 contains time and then 500 companies names in the headers (total width of 501 cells)

Comment: `var_name='company'` is an option that makes it so, that the column that contains the companies has the name 'company'.

Comment: I get the     raise KeyError(key) from err
KeyError: 'Year'

Comment: This most likely means that your df_1 does not contain the 'Year' column with an uppercase 'Y'. The DataFrame in your question has the column 'year' with a lowercase 'y'. Maybe that's the problem?

Comment: Thank you so much! Im still getting an error when merging tho :/ it says: `pandas.errors.MergeError: No common columns to perform merge on. Merge options: left_on=None, right_on=None, left_index=False, right_index=False`     here is the df1 and df2 just before merging: https://imgur.com/a/hgTbILG

Comment: in df_1 the column name 'company' is in lowercase letters and in df_2 it is 'Company' with a capital 'C'. Changing the naming in this line: `df_1 = df_1.melt(id_vars='year', var_name='Company')` should solve the problem.

Comment: thakns for answer, I don't think that's the issue, cuz I changed it but the error message stayed the same :/ code: https://imgur.com/a/XdQjRWk  dataframes: https://imgur.com/a/w5Xf3sE

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246319/discussion-between-vogelstein-and-sam333).